# Redireccionar de manera inmediata con SELENIUM PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

Hago un inicio de sesion e ingreso pero me redireccionan a una pagina la cual posee errores y se queda cargando.Las credenciales se conservan aun asi la pagina no cargue por completo.

La pagina presenta un bucle que no deja de recargar el sitio.

Yo despues de el inicio de sesion lo redirecciono a otro link funcional pero tengo que esperar 1 min a que la pagina anterior se destrabe.

Alguien sabe como redirecciono de manera inmediata.

Utilizo como driver phantomjs.

Comment: Ese lo tilizo pero la pagina empieza recargarse sola es un error del sitio y pone lento el script

Comment: No hay una forma de forzar el cambio de url? @FJSevilla

Comment: Tambien podria ser que se abra una nueva pestaña para abril la otra url y conservar las credenciales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mi caso era un error de sitio web, se generaba una clase de bucle.

Para solucionar esto importe lo siguiente:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Asi que estableci un tiempo limite al cargue de la pagina con la siguiente linea:

```
browser.set_page_load_timeout(2)
```

Y controle el error si se pasaba del tiempo que yo le asigne asi:

```
try:
    login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_name("loginButton2").click()
    pass    
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```